# try to display username on custom sidebar and it's giving me the error message below

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app**

   import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

   ```
                 import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
            import { selectUser,logout } from '../../features/userSlice';


     const CustomSidebarMenu  = (props) => {
          const user = useSelector(selectUser);
          return (
            <View style={stylesSidebar.sideMenuContainer}>
              <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeader}>

                <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderPicCircle}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#307ecc'}}>
                  {'MANS React'.charAt(0)}
                  </Text>
                </View>

                <Text style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderText}>
            {user.Username}
                </Text>
              </View>


              <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderLine} />

              <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <DrawerItemList {...props} />

                <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', marginVertical:20,borderWidth:2,borderColor: '#000'}} />



                <DrawerItem
                  icon={({color,size}) => (
                    <Icon
                    name="exit-to-app"
                    color={color}
                    size={size}
                    />
                )}
                label="Logout"
                  onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
                    Alert.alert(
                      'Logout',
                      'Are you sure? You want to logout?',
                      [
                        {
                          text: 'Cancel',
                          onPress: () => {
                            return null;
                          },
                        },
                        {
                          text: 'Confirm',
                          onPress: () => {
                            AsyncStorage.clear();
                                // dispatch(logout());
                            props.navigation.replace('Auth');
                          },
                          // onPress : handleLogout()
                        },
                      ],
                      {cancelable: false},
                    );
                  }}
                />
              </DrawerContentScrollView>
            </View>

            // </Provider>
          );
        };
   ```

Comment: can you paste the full code ?

Comment: The error is saying your issue is with hooks . But i don't see any hooks being used in the code which you have shared .

Comment: please check the code now @Shyam

Comment: what is this `selectUser` ? can you add that code as well ?

Comment: select user is coming from a state

Comment: even when i use any hook inside that function it still gives the same error, even this

  const [vote, setVote] =useState('');
@Shyam

Comment: Hmm . That's strange . Does the error message gives you a stack trace on from which file the error is ?

Comment: Where and how do you call this component? Can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the useSelector function . useSelector function takes a function as an argument and allows us to read the specific piece of state from the store.

consider you have the store with the below structure

```
{
  user: 'fmans'
}
```

The to read it you need to write your useSelector as

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
```